# How much damage do grenades deal per second?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Can anyone tell me what the effective rate of fire is for grenade throwing, for working out how damage per second compares to guns?

Comment: Do you want to know for the first Borderlands game or the Pre Sequel?

Comment: Primarily the Pre Sequel, but I'd guess it's same rules for BL2, which is why I didn't specify. If anyone knows the ROF in BL2 then I'm happy enough to assume it's the same again (everything else in TPS seems to be).

Comment: Question title seems misleading. I was sure you want to know the amount of damage over time grenades do... Maybe "How fast are grenades thrown" or "Grenade "fire rate""?

Comment: Mod re-worded the title but I don't think it's misleading when you read the full question.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I have not been able to find an effective "rate of fire" for grenades, however after just throwing grenades for a bit I would say that you throw them at a rate of around 1.0-1.1 about 1 per second (this is just me doing a little working out and might not be representative of actual throw rate). However the DPS will be greatly reliant on what type of [grenade](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Grenade_Mod) you are using in conjunction with the prefix . For example a longbow with a fuse time of 0.0 will get to and explode faster than a rubberised AOE with a fuse time of 2.3, therefore having a greater burst damage where as the AOE will have a greater sustained damage. Unless you are using a [Bomber](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bomber_Oz_Kit) O2 kit that has a free grenade chance and increased grenade damage, I would suggest using grenades in a more supportive role, such as a singularity for CC, a tesla for gaining [maelstrom](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Maelstrom) stacks for Athena or simply a lobbed into a group of enemies to gain a reprieve from their unrelenting onslaught. But of course it is up to you to play the game in anyway that you see fit and to enjoy it :) Hope this helped.

Comment: That is a **Bomber Oz Kit**, not a COM.

Comment: Indeed it is, I have incorporated it in the answer

Comment: Thanks cutypi, one per second is also the rate I've observed but I wasn't sure if the ROF stat on guns is rounds per second. That would normally be my assumption but based on observation of the number of rounds fired over time, I'm not sure that 11 ROF for example is 11 rounds per second, so I'm not sure we can assume 1 grenade per second equates to 1 ROF. This seemed to change between BL1 and BL2 where a given ROF number is faster in BL1 in rounds/sec terms than in BL2.

Comment: Oh and just to explain in gameplay terms why this interests me... for boss fights, deploying drones (or turret in BL1/BL2) and pelting the boss with grenades while it focuses on my drones / turret is an approach I've generally found to be very effective for bosses (switching to launcher when my grenades run out or shotgun if they keep getting too close) so I'm just wondering in damage per second how my grenade mods stack up to my launchers.

Comment: When I said "rate of fire" I was referring to grenades thrown per second, as you say the ROF could be 3.8 for 1 grenade per second. just doing some quick tests it seems to me that the ROF for weapons is representative of the number of bullets that they fir per second and not just a number which equates to a specific number of bullets. For example a Dahl torrent with a fire rate of 11.2 will empty a 50 bullet mag in a little under 5 seconds (I haven't got the exact time yet) and a Badaboom with a ROF of 1 will empty a 10 rocket mag in approximately 10 seconds. (more to come with specific times)

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to test! Gotta say I'm surprised by those results. I found in BL1, a pistol with 4.5 ROF would fire as fast as you can click the mouse button. In BL2, a 4.5 pistol is nowhere near as fast as the button, and you'd need 10-15 ROF (Dahl or Jakobs) to fire as fast as you can click. You're timing with a stopwatch?

Comment: Yeah i'm using a stopwatch, and it would also change with the manufacturers bonus for instance a dahl in burst will empty the clip a lot faster than a different gun with the same fire rate. Or perhaps a jackobs where it really only depends on how fast you can click.

Comment: I always assumed the ROF stat on a Dahl pistol or AR would be the non-ADS ROF. I'd think the delay between bursts probably goes a long way to cancelling out the burst rate benefit. I'd suggest testing with something simple like a Vladof pistol or AR - just holding the button and timing how long it takes to empty.